# Digital Elevation Maps (DEM) are Warped yet ReliefPlot renders as a rectangle - how do i join?

Tags: image-processing, geodesy, projection

I downloaded several USGS Digital Elevation Maps (DEM files) corresponding to 12 adjacent areas. Each file Imports[] into *Mathematica* and I can render the individual `ReliefPlot`s easily. The intent was, however, to create a mosaic by joining the individual images. Unfortunately, each DEM is warped and when I render using `ImageAssemble` there are triangular gaps between each `ReliefPlot`.

Does anyone know if there is a simple way of using *Mathematica* to orthogonalise the tiles so they can be assembled without gaps? It seems like `Import` pads the gaps using a number corresponding to a corner thereby creating an array that can be processed by `ReliefPlot`.

I gather the issue stems from fact each tile is a quadrangle defined using UMT coordinates so I'm hoping the Geodesy package will help effect the transformation. However, having looked at the Geodesy functions I can't see the wood for the trees! Is there a simple fix. And is there a tutorial or book for the package?

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked some data and actual code you used together with an image to show how the triangular gaps look. In the meantime, there is quite a lot of how-to's in [this blog](http://mathgis.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/extract-elevation-data-from-google.html) that might help you.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Wolfram Blog post that explains this as a subproblem:

[**Mapping GPS Data**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/17/mapping-gps-data/), by Robert Raguet-Schofield.

That was published in 2009 and I think is pretty nifty. But I'd recommend looking into out new [URLFetchAsynchronous](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/URLFetchAsynchronous.html) and perhaps updating the code. Below you see parts in the blog where he seamlessly goes from patches to a single map:

[image]

[image]